# How to disable a button when a function is running in swift?

Tags: swift

I'm writing my own program in Swift. Here's how I define my button:

```
@IBAction func Button(_ sender: NSButton) {
    //blablabla
}
...
```

To prevent users from spamming this button again and again, I want each time users click this button, it will be disabled until the function completes. I've searched for this on the Internet, and one solution is to use `Button.isEnabled = false`. However, my type of definition does not allow me to use `Button.isEnabled = false`.
It returned this error:

`Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'isEnabled'`

In conclusion, my question is: how to disable the button itself when a function is running? Huge thanks!

Comment: `sender.isEnable = false`

Comment: Where should I put it?

Comment: Show your function code please

Answer (score 1):

It's throwing error because your function's name is `Button`. If you want to disable button, you have to use the variable which represents the button.

```
@IBAction func Button(_ sender: NSButton) {
    sender.isEnabled = false
    //blablabla
    sender.isEnabled = true
}
```

This will keep the button disabled while `blablabla` is being executed

Answer (score 0):

You can disable / enable user interaction and easily handle this issue as-

```
yourButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false // disabled
yourButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true // enabled
```